# Will Service Connect allow me to route requests for www.some-domain.com from one service to another?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-service-connect

I have a backend service which for different reasons needs to be requested on a specific hostname. This also goes for internal requests.

My understanding is that Service Connect will let me set things up so that service A calls service B using e.g. [www.some-domain.com](http://www.some-domain.com).

Is there any limitations on the hostname itself or the number of hostnames I can use with Service Connect for one service to talk to another?